# iterate through a text file and write a new text file for each line python

Tags: python

I am trying to accomplish what seems to be a simple task but I seem to be unable to figure it out. I am a Python rookie.

Here is my task:
I have a text file that contains a list of numbers, each on a separate line...

```
100101
100201
100301
100401
100501
100601
100701
100801
100901
101001
```

What I would like to do is read from the text file and write a new text file for each line in the file that contains the line and is also named using the line...

```
100101.txt
contains one line of text "100101"

100201.txt
contains one line of text "100201"

etc...
```

Hope this makes sense...thanks!

hjnathan

Comment: Removed the [parsing] and [text] tags, because this doesn't involve parsing, and [text] is a fairly useless tag in general.

Comment: This is not homework. This is to help me test some software for work.

Comment: @Levon: I'm curious as to why you ask if a question that shows no effort is homework before you give the OP the codez.

Comment: @Wooble I waited (@ 20 mins?) .. and once I saw responses posted that could be improved I decided to help - plus OP responded that this is not homework. It's a judgement call, and not always easy (nor always easy to make the right call - you try your best)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('data.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        num = line.strip()
        if num:
            fn = '%s.txt' %num
            with open(fn, 'w') as outf:
                outf.write('contains one line of text "%s"\n' %num)
```

Using the `with` construct makes sure each file is closed when it's not needed any longer (or if an exception should occur)

Comment: @joelCornett .. thanks for the edit. I didn't see the need for the check since OP stated there would be a number on each line, but no problem with defensive programming :)

Comment: It makes sense to infer that. I just figured, since OP was asking a pretty basic question, that this problem was likely to arise :)

Comment: @JoelCornett No, you are right, better safe than sorry.

Comment: I get a error message when I try this...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/scripts/read text file", line 1, in <module>
    with open('C:\test2.txt') as inf:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\test2.txt'

Comment: Never mind I figured it out I used a backslash instead of a forward slash in my file path...

Comment: I'm curious, where would I find the output files?

Comment: @user1558287 The files are created in the same directory where the script is run (and where in my case `data.txt` was too).

Comment: @levon I modified the code to get exactly what I want and it works beautifully!! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

Edit: used `with` to make execution safer.

```
lines = open(your_file, 'r')
for line in lines.readlines():
    with open(str(line).rstrip()+'.txt','w') as output_file
        output_file.write(line)
lines.close()
```

Comment: You should probably put in an `output_file.close()`.  Relying on the garbage collector to close your file and free those resources isn't considered good practice. (and a `lines.close()` while you're at it).  Also, there is no need for `readlines` here, `for line in lines` will work just fine.

Comment: This doesn't deal with flushing the buffer or closing the file on IO errors. The `with open(file, mode) as` construct is the proper way of doing this kind of IO as it automatically takes care of all of that stuff.

Comment: Is file mode 'r' as a default guaranteed behavior?

Comment: This also suffers from the same problem as the other answer. `line` comes with a newline attached. Trying to open `"somefile\n.txt"` will generate an IOError. Have you tested this?

Comment: @JoelCornett -- Yes ( http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open )  "If mode is omitted, it defaults to `'r'`"

Comment: Reversed my downvote. Couple of things: 1) Why don't you use the `with` construct with `lines` as well? 2) `str(line)` is unnecessary. 3) `file` objects are already iterators. No need to do `for line in lines.readlines()`, simply `for line in lines`.

Comment: @JoelCornett -- But if those changes were all made, it would be identical to the answer provided already by weirdcanada ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: This question is so simple that it only really has one answer.

Comment: @mgilson: Ideally, "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." ;)

Comment: @JoelCornett -- I know.  Of course your suggestions were correct.  I was more pointing out the (strange) fact that this (worse) answer has 2 votes while the other (better) answer has none.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the below does not check for pre-existing files with the same name.

```
with open('numbers_file.txt','r') as numbers:
    for line in numbers:
        with open(line.rstrip() + '.txt','w') as new_file:
            new_file.write(line)
```

Comment: why `str(line)` instead of just `line`?

Comment: Good call. I was being precautions. Just tested and it works.